# Using Ray to transfer data from Spark to Ray datasets

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, ray

**update:**

I think that I finally understood the issue.. As databricks inits the spark session, the raydb-spark session is not really set up..

So, is there a way to make the raydb-context available in the Spark session?

**pre-update:**
I am currently running Spark on Databricks and set up Ray onto it (head node only).
It seems to work, however, if I try to transfer the data from Spark to Ray datasets, I run into an issue:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2445755691838> in <module>
      5 memory_per_executor = "500M"
      6 # spark = raydp.init_spark(app_name, num_executors, cores_per_executor, memory_per_executor)
----> 7 dataset = ray.data.from_spark(df)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/data/read_api.py in from_spark(df, parallelism)
   1046     import raydp
   1047 
-> 1048     return raydp.spark.spark_dataframe_to_ray_dataset(df, parallelism)
   1049 
   1050 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/raydp/spark/dataset.py in spark_dataframe_to_ray_dataset(df, parallelism, _use_owner)
    176         if parallelism != num_part:
    177             df = df.repartition(parallelism)
--> 178     blocks, _ = _save_spark_df_to_object_store(df, False, _use_owner)
    179     return from_arrow_refs(blocks)
    180 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/raydp/spark/dataset.py in _save_spark_df_to_object_store(df, use_batch, _use_owner)
    150     jvm = df.sql_ctx.sparkSession.sparkContext._jvm
    151     jdf = df._jdf
--> 152     object_store_writer = jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.raydp.ObjectStoreWriter(jdf)
    153     obj_holder_name = df.sql_ctx.sparkSession.sparkContext.appName + RAYDP_OBJ_HOLDER_SUFFIX
    154     if _use_owner is True:

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

with the vanilla code:

```
# loading the data
# CSV options
infer_schema = "true"
first_row_is_header = "true"
delimiter = ","

df = spark.read.format("csv") \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header) \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load("dbfs:/databricks-datasets/nyctaxi/tripdata/green")

import ray
import sys

# disable stdout
sys.stdout.fileno = lambda: False

# connect to ray cluster on a single instance
ray.init()
ray.cluster_resources()

import raydp

dataset = ray.data.from_spark(df)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
pyspark 3.0.1
ray 2.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Databricks now supports Ray-on-Spark (not RayDP). See [Databricks Ray Integration](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/ray-integration.html).

RayDP is "Spark-on-Ray" which is incompatible with Databricks runtime.